# navigate function in Gatsby simple-auth example leads to build error

Tags: gatsby

the simple-auth example in Gatsby works fine in development mode but when I try to build it, it will throw following error

WebpackError: TypeError: window.___navigate is not a function

index.js:233 navigate node_modules/gatsby-link/index.js:233:1

PrivateRoute.js:11 PrivateRoute src/components/PrivateRoute.js:11:14

It seems the error lies in the navigate function which leads to the build error. I googled and find that a fix is to use navigate inside useEffect however, there is no example online which I can refer. I'm trying to solve this. Can anyone who has successfully resolve this build error share how they resolve this build error? Thanks

Below is the PrivateRoute.js component

```js
import React, { Component } from "react"
import { navigate } from "gatsby"
import { isLoggedIn } from "../utils/auth"
    
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, location, ...rest }) => {
  if (!isLoggedIn() && location.pathname !== /admin) {
    navigate("/admin")
    return null
  }
  return <Component {...rest} />
}
    
export default PrivateRoute
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems below work. Anyone thinks my code can be improved are welcome to comment. Hope it helps someone. Thanks

```js
import React, { useEffect, Component } from "react"
import { navigate } from "gatsby"
    
import { isLoggedIn } from "../utils/auth"
    
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, location, ...rest }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    checkLoginStatus()
    // return () => {
    //   cleanup
    // };
  }, [])
    
  const checkLoginStatus = () => {
    if (!isLoggedIn() && location.pathname !== `/admin`) {
      navigate("/admin")
      return null
    }
  }
    
return <Component {...rest} />
}
    
export default PrivateRoute
```

Comment: I believe this will cause a flash of content before navigation? Suppose user is not logged in, but checkLoginStatus is not fired until the component is mounted, so by default this PrivateRoute will return Profile component for a flash second before user is directed back to /admin.